# Initializing and setting a vector<int>

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(0); //you have to do this
//v[0] = 0;     //this gives you an error
v[0] = 1000000; //but now you can set it
```

So, how come the first time you initialize a vector, you have to push_back, and after that you can just set it? For a primitive type, say int, you can do int i = 0; for initialization.

Comment: You should put it this way: ``vector<int> v(size);`` where ``size`` is the number of elements you want in the vector, otherwise it will contain 0 elements and therefore the first element will not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make everything 100% clear, your declaration of a vector,

```
vector<int> v;
```

is in some sense similar to the declaration of a variable:

```
int x;
```

and if you then want, say,

```
cout << x;
```

you will get rubbish. Though, if you declare

```
int x(2);
```

everything will be fine. Similarly for vectors: declaration of

```
vector<int> v;
```

allocates some memory space for a vector, but not fills it. You can then specify

```
vector<int> v(2);
```

which means that you now have declared a vector of two elements, or go for a vector-only feature - push_back. This would add elements to your vector, as you've noticed.

Answer (score 5):

If you know in advance the size of your vector, definitively **don't** use a plain sequence of push_back()'s, since it may be a waste of time reallocating if your vector is large (say, >512 elements).

Better do:

#### OPTION 1: Preallocating and pushing

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(N); // N is the expected size, but right now [0] is undefined. 
for (...) { 
  v.push_back(...);  // No problems in adding more than N elements, but may have to reallocate.        
}
```

#### OPTION 2: Resizing and filling

```
vector<int> v;
v.resize(N);
for (size_t i=0;i<N;i++)
  v[i] = ...; // You can't write past N-1 here!
```

#### OPTION 3: Create directly with the correct size, then fill

```
vector<int> v(N);
for (size_t i=0;i<N;i++)
  v[i] = ...; // You can't write past N-1 here!
```

#### OPTION 4: Create a vector with the correct size and initialized to some fixed value

```
vector<int> v(N,val); // v[0:N-1] are all equal to val
```

Answer (score 4):

Because when you first create a vector it is empty so `vector[0]` doesn't exist. `push_back` adds an element to the vector then you can modify or read it with `vector[i]`

Answer (score 3):

Because `std::vector<int>` isn't `std::map<int, int>`.

`std::vector` requires you to manually `push_back()` or (in C++11) `emplace_back()` elements for them to be included in the collection. And of course some of its constructors allows you to include initial elements to it. And of course again its assignment operators.

The subscript(`[]`) operator should only be used in reading and/or modifying *existing* elements. Indexing using `operator[]` out-of-bounds (non-existent) elements would result in *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `v[0]` because there is no `v[0]` yet. The vector starts off default-constructed as an empty vector. You push an element onto the back and it grows in size by 1. You're then able to access the element you just added. If you want it to start off with one element, use the appropriate constructor:

```
std::vector<int> v(1); //one zeroed integer
```

You're comparing apples and oranges. `int i = 0;` would be like `std::vector<int> v;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should first allocate memory for setting element values, such as

```
v.resize(new_size);
```

or use `push_back` method to add elements.